# Is there any way to create an internal pull request in github?

Tags: git, github

In Azure DevOps, I'm able to create a pull request from a branch without forking the repo. Is there any way to do this in github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there are several ways in Github. For example:

#### Create PR from code tab

[image]

#### Create PR from branches overview

[image]

#### Create PR from recently pushed

After push (with and without fork), there is a notification where you could create a PR:

[image]

#### Docs

See the [Creating a pull request on github.com](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-pull-request)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helps you.

1. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. In the "Branch" menu, choose the branch that contains your commits.
3. To the right of the Branch menu, click New pull request.
4. Use the base branch dropdown menu to select the branch you'd like to merge your 
   changes into, then use the compare branch drop-down menu to choose the topic 
   branch you made your changes in.
5. Type a title and description for your pull request.
6. o create a pull request that is ready for review, click Create Pull Request. To 
   create a draft pull request, use the drop-down and select Create Draft Pull 
   Request, then click Draft Pull Request. For more information about draft pull 
   requests, see "About pull requests."